# Short circuit in welding

Tags: welding, current, shock

All I know about welding is it is a technique in which electrode is connected to one terminal and the gripper connected to workpiece is in connection with the other terminal. As current passes and when the electrode is touched to the workpiece,an arc is generated which melts electrode and helps in the formation of a joint. As the circuit is completed with a conductor in-between,doesn't it result in short circuit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not classed as a "short-circuit". This is a circuit with a designed current flow - ie a 60 to 150A range is common...

A "short-circuit" is a circuit where the current flow is not following the designed current path ie it is taking a "shorter" route to ground.

Comment: To expand a little. There *is* a circuit, but the welder limits the amount of current it puts out instead of letting it increase to a very high value. Current flowing through a wire (or through conductors making a circuit, including the cables, electrode, and plasma) generates heat, and that heat is generally where the electrical resistance in the circuit is high - which happens to be where the welding is taking place.

Comment: At that point, the resistance relative to other parts of the system (large cables, big pieces of steel, etc) is fairly high.

Comment: And , yes there is a "short arc" welding mode used with MIG ( wire feed welding) where the filler wire is heated as a short circuit then melts and drops. It requires a welding machine that instantaneously adjusts current and amperage to do this. It is used for low heat input welds. More common MIG process is the "spray arc" mode .